# ImportError: No module named datadog

Tags: python, datadog

I'm new to datadog. I followed this [post](http://docs.datadoghq.com/api/), and replaced in my app/api keys.

I have : `nginx_dd.py`

```
# Make sure you replace the API and/or APP key below
# with the ones for your account

from datadog import initialize, api
import time

options = {
    'api_key': '***',
    'app_key': '***'
}

initialize(**options)

now = int(time.time())
query = 'system.cpu.idle{*}by{host}'
print api.Metric.query(start=now - 3600, end=now, query=query)
```

---

When I run it `python nginx_dd.py`, I kept getting

> ImportError: No module named datadog

---

Any hints / suggestions on this will be a huge helps !

Comment: Did you install it? Did you use a virtual env? If so, are you pointing to the right virtual env?

Comment: I installed in a Mac. I already created an account, and sign-in on the datadog site. What did I miss ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Verify if the datadog package is installed in your environment.

You can do this with this command:

```
$ pip freeze | grep datadog
```

If it's not installed, you can install it with this command:

```
$ pip install datadog
```